# Function that takes a String parameter and reverses it C++

Tags: c++

I want to create a function that takes a string parameter, reverses it and returns the reversed string. There have been some answers, but none work fully. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


string revStr(string word){

    string reversed = "";

    if(word.size() == 0)
    {
        return reversed;
    }

    for (int i = word.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
        reversed = reversed+word[i];
    }

    return reversed;
}

int main(){
string strin;
cout << "enter string;" << endl;
cin>> strin;
cout << revStr(strin);
}
```

This works only for strings that do not contain a space. When I type in Hello World, it return olleH.

Comment: There's also `std::reverse` from `<algorithm>`

Comment: Which part doesn't work, the input or the reversing? Reducing the problem helps solving it, that's the conclusion you should draw from this.

Comment: Try to put a line `cout << strin;` right after the `cin>> strin;` and you should spot the problem :)

Comment: Try using `std::getline(std::cin, strin)` instead of `std::cin >> strin`.

Answer (score 4):

[`basic_string::operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt):

> 2) Behaves as an FormattedInputFunction. After constructing and checking the sentry object, which may skip leading whitespace, first clears `str` with `str.erase()`, then reads characters from is and appends them to `str` as if by `str.append(1, c)`, until one of the following conditions becomes true: *[...]*
>
> **`std::isspace(c,is.getloc())` is true for the next character c in is (this whitespace character remains in the input stream)**.

The method you use by definition reads until a white-space, so you read only `Hello` into `strin`. You should use another method for reading like `getline` or `stringstream`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `std::getline` to input strings with a space.

For reversing your `std::string`, consider using `std::reverse` from `<algorithm>`, although your algorithm is correct too.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string strin;
    cout << "enter string;" << endl;
    getline(cin,strin);
    reverse(strin.begin() , strin.end() );
    cout << strin;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See, cin halts the input at any occurrence of a space or a newline character. So, to input a string with spaces, you'd have to use `cin.getline()` and that can be done by using the following snippet:

```
string S;
cin.getline(1000,'\n');
```

This would take input till the newline character into `string S` and then we just have to reverse the string, and that can be done in two ways.

Method 1:

Using `std::reverse` from `<algorithm>` header file. This function works with all containers and takes iterators as parameters.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    string S;
    getline(cin,S);
    reverse(S.begin(), S.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Method 2:

You can create your function which swaps the characters at positions equidistant from end and start, and you get what you need in `O(n)` time-complexity.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

string myfunc(string S)
{
    int l = 0;
    int r = S.size()-1; 
    while(l<r)
    {
        swap(S[l],S[r]);
        l++;
        r--;
    }
    return S;
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    string S;
    getline(cin,S);
    S = myfunc(S);
    cout<<S;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What I think is you could do fine with your `revStr()` but you need to get a whole line input, but using `cin` considers space as a delimiter, hence you get only `Hello` out of `Hello World`.

Replace `cin >> strin` with `getline(cin,strin)`.